# Background color of edit post page

Tags: visual-editor, wp-editor, post-editor

I noticed that the background color of the post editor page is different for different post types. Sometimes it is white, some times it is not. I'm attaching a screenshot of non-white example. Is this supposed to be like this or have I messed something up again? Is it possible to change this color to white, I would be more comfortable with white.

[image]

Comment: It's likely determined by your theme. It might be possible to adjust from a child theme, but it depends on how the original theme works. You should contact its author for assistance.